# Validación de form me devuelve error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Tengo un form con varios campos, y para validar de que esté bien "llenado", estoy utilizando `Jquery`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#frmContactoCreate').validate({
            rules: {
                ClienteId: {
                    required: true
                },
                SucursalId: {
                    required: true
                },
                Nombre: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 100,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                Correo: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                Departamento: {
                    required: true
                },
                Puesto: {
                    required: true
                },
                TelefonoOficina: {
                    required: true
                },
                TelefonoMovil: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                ClienteId: {
                    required: "Debe seleccionar un Cliente"
                },
                SucursalId: {
                    required: "Debe seleccionar una Sucursal"
                },
                Nombre: {
                    required: "Debe ingresar un nombre",
                    maxlength: "Longitud máxima es de 100",
                    minlength: "Longitud mínima es de 2",
                },
                Correo: {
                    required: "Debe ingresar un correo válido",
                },
                Departamento: {
                    required: "Debe ingresar un Departamento"
                },
                Puesto: {
                    required: "Debe ingresar un Puesto"
                },
                TelefonoOficina: {
                    required: "Debe ingresar un numero de oficina"
                },
                TelefonoMovil: {
                    required: "Debe ingresar un numero movil"
                }
            }
        });

    });
```

Pero me devuelve un error que dice

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "call",
> a.validator.methods[d] is undefined.  Exception occurred when checking
> element Nombre, check the '**dummy**' method.

Me dice que es el `Nombre` pero viendo otras validaciones que tengo iguales, no se que más pueda ser.

Utilizo los healpers de `asp.net` para el form.

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="iXow66SoDGmxsWW00ytLp6oHFejkTIy5ceNym3tgXuj6QHtt2L9NoFptuVossxYXtgmWp_f2RthDbw23tfpxLzMf5cb-VQx2fB5Whchb0-cLzazqkSLzC12Y1a5B5THwj1R-s9itPma5EGU-obCNkg2">    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-primary">
                <div class="card-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Contacto</h3>
                </div>
                
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <hr>
              
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="Clientes">Clientes</label>

                            <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="ClienteId" name="ClienteId" style="width:100%" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="ClienteId"><option value="1" data-select2-id="88">ReaClima</option>

                             </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap4" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="87" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-ClienteId-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-ClienteId-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="ReaClima">ReaClima</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="SucursalId">Sucursal</label>

                            <select class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" id="SucursalId" name="SucursalId" style="width:100%" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="SucursalId">undefined<option value="1" data-select2-id="91">Matriz</option></select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap4" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="90" style="width: 100%;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-SucursalId-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-SucursalId-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Matriz">Matriz</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SucursalId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="Nombre">Nombre</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo Nombre es obligatorio." id="Nombre" name="Nombre" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Nombre" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="Correo">Correo</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Correo" name="Correo" type="email" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Correo" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="Departamento">Departamento</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Departamento" name="Departamento" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Departamento" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="Puesto">Puesto</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Puesto" name="Puesto" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Puesto" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="TelefonoOficina">Telefono de Oficina</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-inputmask="'mask': '(999) 999-9999'" data-mask="" id="TelefonoOficina" name="TelefonoOficina" type="tel" value="" inputmode="text">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="TelefonoOficina" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="TelefonoMovil">Telefono Movil</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-inputmask="'mask': '(999) 999-9999'" data-mask="" id="TelefonoMovil" name="TelefonoMovil" type="tel" value="" inputmode="text">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="TelefonoMovil" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="MultiSucursal">MultiSucursal</label>
                            <br>
                            <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo MultiSucursal es obligatorio." id="MultiSucursal" name="MultiSucursal" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="MultiSucursal" type="hidden" value="false">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="MultiSucursal" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" onclick="AgregarContacto()" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">Cancelar</span></button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Agrega el código (mínimo) del HTML del formulario, para poder realizar pruebas y reproducir el error. Además agrega las versiones de JQuery y Validate

Comment: lo omití sin darme cuenta, la acabo de editar

Comment: Pero el error es de javascript (en el navegador) o en el servidor???? Si fuese lo primero por favor coloca el código html generado (no el Razor), esto lo puedes hacer copiando desde el código de fuente del navegador (Ctrl + u)

Comment: Lo que me falla en el javascript